# Is the qira'a "There has certainly come to you a Messenger from among your most precious" accepted?

Tags: quran, arabic, qiraat, uloom-al-quran

In surat at-Tawba we have in ([9:128](http://legacy.quran.com/9/128)) the known qira'a:

> لَقَدْ جَاءَكُمْ رَسُولٌ **مِّنْ أَنفُسِكُمْ** عَزِيزٌ عَلَيْهِ مَا عَنِتُّمْ حَرِيصٌ عَلَيْكُم بِالْمُؤْمِنِينَ رَءُوفٌ رَّحِيمٌ
>
> transliterated:  Laqad jaakum rasoolun **min anfusikum**AAazeezun AAalayhi ma AAanittum hareesunAAalaykum bilmu/mineena raoofun raheem
>
> Translation: There has certainly come to you a Messenger **from among yourselves**. Grievous to him is what you suffer; [he is] concerned over you and to the believers is kind and merciful. (Sahih International)

I've heard that there is/was another qira'a saying:

> **مِّنْ أَنفَسِكُمْ**
>   transliterated: **min anfasikum**

which may be translated as:

> from among your most valuable/precious

instead of

> مِّنْ أَنفُسِكُمْ

which means from among yourselvs, whom you know etc.

My question is:
Is this a valid qira'a among the 7 or 10 qira'at al mutawatirah or what is the actual rulig about it?

Answer (score 2):

**This is not one of the mutawatir qiraat**. This verse has **12** different qiraat accredited to the 7 letters. Some of who read it with fat-ha over f letter [ مِّنْ أَنفَسِكُمْ  transliterated: min anfasikum] are:

الضحاك Ad-dahhak,

ابن عباسibnu Abbas,

ابو العالية Abu Al Aliya,

ابن محيصن ibnu Muhaysin,

عبد الله بن قسيط المكي Abdullah ibnu Qusayt Al makki.

You can get a copy of the Al- Muhtaseb المحتسب Authored by Othman ibnu Jinna. page 92.